Excel Solver won't let me optimize when I use CountiF or IF statements
My current setup
My solver problem
I am trying to use the Excel optimization module solver to find the best blend of 24 hour values.
The problem is that I only want to be able to optimize using 2 of the shapes as opposed to all 5.
Cells k2 through 02 are a variation of =IF(K3<>0,1,0) to get a binary 1,0 value on if that shape is used.
Cells k3-o3 are a weight which will be modified.
M2 is the sum of the shapes used, M3 is the sum of the percentage, and we're trying to minimize on the sum of squared error.
How can I set up this problem to introduce a limit to the amount of shapes I can use?
I tried multiple different variations of if statements for excel, but I determined that this is not the correct way to set up the optimization module.
